# Impact of Thread.Sleep() in a continuous loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sleep, infinite-loop

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void MyRunningThread()
{
    while(counter>0) // counter is a Class member that can get modified from external     //threads
    {
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Suppose I start a Thread on the above function.

Now, is it a bad to have a never ending loop like this inside a Thread? 
I have added Thread.Sleep() with the assumption that context switching to this function will occur at a less frequency due to the Sleep and hence reduce Resource consumption by this Thread.

Could someone verify my points.

Comment: why don't use sync objects instead?

Comment: @Tigran: Any good reading reference to understand Sync Objects?

Comment: @Shamim: Make your code a bit more specific and you might get a better answer.

Comment: @Shahim: just msdn, for example:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179(v=VS.100).aspx but I think you will find a lot of more by just googling.

Comment: @Henk: I wasn't actually looking for an exact answer, but to discuss if there are obvious flaws in my approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is far from optimal, wasting a Thread .

You should consider using a Timer or a WaitHandle or something. Without more details it's not possible to be precise.

But your current approach is not disastrous or anything, provided that that other thread uses `lock` or `InterLocked` to change the counter.

Comment: This never ending loop actually monitors other Threads, where each running Thread would decrement the value of the counter. That means, when the Counter value is 0 when all Threads being monitored have stopped execution. The counter value is set to max value prior to starting any Thread. One note though, I never use any Lock. Do you think it may create any issue. I was thinking all Threads attempt to reduce counter value by 1.

Comment: It may happen that counter will become less than zero.

Comment: @Shamim: You should at least use `Interlocked.Increment()` and `.Decrement()` to change the counter. But maybe you should be using Tasks (TPL). And if nothing happens inside the loop, a WaitHandle or CountDown object is more to the point.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use System.Threading.SpinWait instead of sleep, this article explains how to use it http://www.emadomara.com/2011/08/spinwait-and-lock-free-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate your problem more? Why do you need to wait in another thread? Anyway, if you need to wait until some counter becomes zero you may consider to use [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx)